# zod TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_parse')

Tags: javascript, typescript, zod

I have a Vite library using Zod. I want to parse configurations and my folder structure is similiar to the configuration object structure. `index.ts` files always export all files in their own directory and everything from their subdirectories e.g. `export * from './subDir';` so the root file exports "the whole lib".

The following setup shows a single configuration branch

[Sample code on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitest-dev-vitest-fchtxz)

```
.
├── src
│   ├── api
│   │   ├── dataSources
|   |   |   ├── dataSource
|   |   |   |   ├── following
|   |   |   |   |   ├── computed
|   |   |   |   |   |   ├── followingComputedDataSourceConfigurationSchema.ts ( extends dataSourceConfigurationSchema )
|   │   │   |   |   |   └── index.ts
|   |   |   |   |   ├── entity
|   |   |   |   |   |   ├── followingEntityDataSourceConfigurationSchema.ts ( extends leadingDataSourceConfigurationSchema )
|   │   │   |   |   |   └── index.ts
|   │   │   |   |   └── index.ts
|   |   |   |   ├── leading
|   |   |   |   |   ├── leadingDataSourceConfigurationSchema.ts ( extends dataSourceConfigurationSchema )
|   │   │   |   |   └── index.ts
|   |   |   |   ├── dataSourceConfigurationSchema.ts ( base schema )
│   │   |   |   └── index.ts
|   |   |   ├── dataSourcesConfigurationSchema.ts ( expects leading and array of followings )
│   │   |   └── index.ts
|   |   ├── apiConfigurationSchema.ts ( expects dataSources )
│   │   └── index.ts
│   └── index.ts 
└── test
    └── basic.test.ts
```

The problem is that I think I'm running into circular dependency imports. I checked the schema with a test using Vitest

```
it('fails.', () => {
  expect(() => apiConfigurationSchema.parse({})).not.toThrow();
});
```

By doing so I get the following error

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_parse')

I don't want to merge the schemas into a single big file because subdirectories might also contain custom validation functions for this specific section.

Do you have any ideas how to fix this setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a cyclic dependency (in 2 `index.ts`)

```
// index.ts
export { apiConfigurationSchema } from './apiConfigurationSchema';
export * from './dataSources';
```

```
// apiConfigurationSchema.ts
import { dataSourcesConfigurationSchema } from '.';
export const used = __use(dataSourcesConfigurationSchema )
```

where you import and use re-exported `*` BEFORE it gets re-exported

So, all you need to fix is...

```
// index.ts
export * from './dataSources';
export { apiConfigurationSchema } from './apiConfigurationSchema';
```

... just to swap two lines in two files

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitest-dev-vitest-8uh3ya?file=src/api/index.ts

---

---

research details: I've created a file

```
// a.ts
import { apiConfigurationSchema } from './src/api/apiConfigurationSchema';
apiConfigurationSchema.parse({});
```

, installed `tsx` package, ran `tsx watch a`, and looked for where the error is until it was fixed

Comment: Thanks a lot for the research details. With this I was able to fix the whole config :)