# Are circular references ok in .d.ts files?

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6-module-loader, typescript-declarations

When creating typescript declarations for a javascript library, is it ok to have circular imports in .d.ts files? E.g.:

file a.d.ts

```
import { B } from "./b";
export class A { ... }
...
```

file b.d.ts

```
import { A } from "./a";
export interface B { ... }
...
```

As I understand, these are only used for compilation.  Let's assume there are no circular dependencies in the javascript library.  So far i did not find any problems when using declarations like above in a test program.  My question is, is this sort of practice ok, or considered bad design that should be avoided?  I understand that the same approach would cause problems at run-time (undefined exports, etc.), but at compile-time it seems that typescript compiler is able resolve these (perhaps by merging all declarations into one module?).  Or am I missing something and this practice should be avoided? If so, can you give an example when this would cause a problem when using such .d.ts files?

Comment: Try it. If it works, it works. If it doesn't, you need to either change around where you have things or rethink your types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0. When you create declarations for existing JS libraries, you don't have to care if it's good or bad, just type it as it is. TS was made to cover as much JS as possible so if it works in JS it'll probably work in TS.
1. Circular references in types are very common, and sometimes unavoidable e.g.

```
// `parent` can't be just a common interface because exact typings are needed and and DRY
class A {
   parent?: A | B
}
class B {
   parent?: A | B
}
```

or circular generics

```
class A<T> { b?: B<T> }
class B<T> { a?: A<T> }
```

so they are OK. What's not OK is that you are using full imports. You should be using

```
import type { A } from './a'
//     ^^^^ says it doesn't actually imports that in runtime
```

2. Runtime circular references in TS code are OK as well - as long as they instantiated before access. This may be not supported by `commonjs` modules tho.

```
// e.g. used in both A and B classes
function makeAorB(x: boolean): A | B { return x ? new A() : new B() }
```

Example of failing instantiation would be [zod TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_parse')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75945904/zod-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-parse/75964760#1)

3. If you have a lot of types, and bundle the code or whatever, you may use https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/api-extractor to rollup the types into a sindle d.ts file

Comment: So in your example in 1, it would be ok if classes A and B are declared in separate .d.ts files and exported, but inside these files they should be imported via "import type"?

Comment: @YevgeniyP the proper way would be to follow the JS source. If './a' IMPORTS `import './b'` or `import {...} from './b'` in runtime, it should be `import`. If './a' doesn't `import './b'` in runtime, it should be `import type`. I.e. same as it would be in TS file that could generate this d.ts

Comment: What if some or all of those files contain only declarations used at compile time (e.g. interfaces and types), so there is no JS source for them?  If I use "import type" in them, then using circular imports in these files would not be a problem?

Comment: Yes. Circular `import type` is good, circular `import` is okay-ish, and the bad one is only runtime circular import IF it crashes the app immediately. If it does not crash the app, it's ok.